# Possible to merge and sum the values of an array?

Tags: templating, array, merge

I have a super table that has 4 columns. I'm trying to create an array based off one column (`contentType`) and merges to get only the unique values while taking the sum of a different column (`points`). Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Based off that screenshot I would have the following results:

- Motivation-To-Achieve : 2
- Emotional-Stability : 2
- Openness : 4

I'm able to get the unique content types, however, I can't figure out how to take the sum of the points column. This is what I have so far:

```
{% set results = {} %}

{% for row in entry.surveyData %}
    {% set type = row.contentType %}
    {% set pts = row.points %}
    {% set results = results|merge({ (type) : {'name': type, 'points': pts } }) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So you'd want the final sum to equal 8?

Comment: No, I have the desired results just below the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to add the `row.points` to any existing points for each `type`, before merging – otherwise you'll just overwrite the existing type/attribute and its values (in other words, the `|merge` filter won't automatically merge number values inside an object).

Something like this should work – note the use of the `|default` filter, to fall back to `0` if the `results[type]` key doesn't exist:

```
{% set results = {} %}

{% for row in entry.surveyData %}
    {% set type = row.contentType %}
    {% set pts = row.points + results[type].points|default(0) %}
    {% set results = results|merge({ (type) : {'name': type, 'points': pts } }) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Clever! However, getting a error on the front-end `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /../craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(403) : eval()'d code on line 67`. Does this have to do with the `results[type]` being in brackets vs curly braces?

Comment: No – I just made a typo in my original answer. It should be `results[type].points`, not `results[type]` – sorry about that, see edit above :)

Comment: Fantastic! It's working. Thanks for the help Mats.

Comment: No problem. Great that it worked out :)